# Can this notation be computed in Mathematica?

Tags: function-construction

I defined a notation as follows:

(a, b) = $a^b$,

(a, b(c)) = (a, b-1(c)) * (a+1, b(c-1)),

(a, b(0)) = (a, b), and (a, 1(c)) = (a, a(c-1)).

For c = 4, (a, b(c)) is already tedious to evaluate. I next defined (a, b(0,1)) to be equal to (a, b($a^b$)) and (a, b(c, 1)) as (a, b-1(c,1)) * (a+1, b(c-1,1). (2, 2(1,1)) is greater than $10^{10000}$, and has so far taken me over a week to evaluate as I only have formulas for (a, b(2)) and (a, b(3)).
Can (a, b(c)) be programmed in Mathematica? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How should be understand `b-1(c)` in your second definition? It seems that `1(c)` is defined later as `a(c-1)`, so should `b-1(c) == b - a (c - 1)`? Or should it be $(b-1) \times (c)$? You may also want to use some other operator that is not multiplication in your expressions in Mathematica, since things like `1(c)` would automatically be simplified.

Comment: In any case, you'll probably need `Nest` or `Fold`.

Answer (score 15):

Roman's solution gets very slow as the value b or c increases. I use Memoization below to prevent recomputing values. We should also ensure b and c are positive integers to avoid infinite recursion. My improved version that does all that is here.

```
Clear[f];
f[a_, b_] := a^b;
f[a_, b_, 0] := a^b;
f[a_, 1, c_Integer?Positive] := f[a,1,c] = f[a,a,c-1]
f[a_, b_Integer?Positive, c_Integer?Positive] := f[a,b,c] = f[a,b-1,c]*f[a+1,b,c-1]
```

Comment: Alternative to `c_Integer?Positive` is `c_Integer/;c>0`.

Answer (score 13):

You can write $(a,b(c))$ as `f[a,b,c]`:

```
f[a_, b_] = a^b;
f[a_, b_, 0] = f[a, b];
f[a_, 1, c_] := f[a, a, c - 1]
f[a_, b_, c_] := f[a, b - 1, c]*f[a + 1, b, c - 1]
```

examples:

```
f[1, 2, 3]
(*    15552    *)

f[3, 2, 1]
(*    432    *)

f[4, 4, 4]
(*    19393983827718432382942097517695828647998395142202754928834510298705433141104807237509816216475619585550730636347520400973355250128278033815331515175151864224862276548634782796395405263354886224119286448795750466960120269181334154615594100146469053340917944759980663872462182165749651283641595899665986474356606642225885307385859438341031898136637724087018412941823577813683669698799074676100519019046540622228028082879315049653248249344010970369039835332134345637888000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000    *)
```

Comment: Can you tell me why it's appropiate here to use = (Set) instead of := (SetDelayed) for your first/second line? I always use SetDelayed whenever I have an argument (like a_) but without a good reason.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion I don't see a reason to delay these assignments, so why delay them? For the second line, for example, an immediate assignment means the right-hand side is evaluated at definition time to $a^b$; if you delay this assignment, then any time we use it we are effectively launching another lookup to `f[a,b]` which yields `a^b` which yields $a^b$; this seems unreasonable/excessively complex to me.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation for `Set` under "Possible Issues" is the example `x=5; f[x_]=x^2; f[2]` which returns `25`. The issue is "In the presence of global variables, pattern variables may show unexpected behavior" which illustrates the need for `SetDelayed`.

Comment: @Somos you're technically right but pointing out a deeper problem. Defining global variables and thus messing up a local scope is one of the reasons why global variables are considered bad style. Another reason is code testability.